# Meteor loses connection to the database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-connection, mlab

I'm running an instance of Meteor on Digital Ocean, and hosting the Mongo database on Mongolab. If the site has been idle for a few hours, and someone goes to a specific page, Meteor appears to drop its connection with the database for 3-15 minutes, without any errors or any warnings. Here's what I've been able to figure out:

**The Meteor Server on DigitalOcean**

- Continues to run, and `Meteor.status()` shows an active connection
- CPU load drops during an episode
- Will continue to serve up copies of the webapp.

**The MongoDB on Mongolab**

- Query operations drop to almost-zero
- Page Faults spike
- Network-out traffic drops to nothing.
- Can still be accessed and queried directly.
- Other servers (workers) using the same database carry on as usual.

I suspect that it has something to do with the following publication:

```
Meteor.publish('spaceUtilSpace', function(view_id, space_id){
  if(!checkSpaceUtilPermissions(view_id, "View Reader", this.userId)) { this.ready(); return; }

  var thisUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  var thisView = View_SpaceUtil.findOne({_id: view_id});

  if(thisView){
    var thisSpace = Spaces.findOne({_id: space_id});

    return [
      View_SpaceUtil.find({_id: view_id}),
      Bldgs.find({_id: thisSpace.localID.bldg_id}),
      Spaces.find({_id: space_id}),
      Schedule.find({"localID.space_id":space_id, startDateMs:{$lte:thisView.time.toDate}, endDateMs:{$gte:thisView.time.fromDate}})
    ]
  }
})
```

I suspect the problem is most likely in this line:
`Schedule.find({"localID.space_id":space_id, startDateMs:{$lte:thisView.time.toDate}, endDateMs:{$gte:thisView.time.fromDate}})`, as that's my largest collection (~80,000 documents, 150 MB).

At first I thought I might just need an index for this query, that it was simply taking too long to process this particular query, but after creating an index for `{"localID.space_id":1, startDateMs:-1, endDateMs:1}`, I'm still having the same problem.

I'm starting to run low on ideas as to how to fix this, so any suggestions would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

**More Info**

Going through the Mongo logs, I've found the following two lines:

```
2015-12-04T08:11:09.904-0800 I QUERY    [conn51589] query myDatabase.schedule query: { localID.space_id: "mjEYjonRaFrrr8gcX", startDateMs: { $lte: 1451520000000.0 }, endDateMs: { $gte: 1262304000000.0 } } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:78172 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:6664 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 13330 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6665 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6665 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6665 } } } 232971ms
2015-12-04T08:11:10.429-0800 I QUERY    [conn51593] query myDatabase.schedule query: { localID.space_id: "mjEYjonRaFrrr8gcX", startDateMs: { $lte: 1451520000000.0 }, endDateMs: { $gte: 1262304000000.0 } } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:78172 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:610 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1222 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 611 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 611 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 611 } } } 128ms
```

It appears that the problem is one query is taking an incredibly long time to complete, and isn't allowing new queries to be made until it completes.

What's confusing me on these two are that the query itself is identical, but the 'acquireCount' for the first one has 10x contents, and took ~2000x longer to return. These fields are indexed...any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: I haven't used Mongolab, so don't know what kind of analytics they give you. Hopefully they have something that shows query performance measurements - if not, you can use Kadira or MongoDB profiling to figure out if this specific query (or some other) is creating problems. I haven't experienced this problem myself, so I can't help much more - but I am inclined to think that this is most likely a DB-side problem more than anything (other options are Meteor or network problems).

Comment: Also, very important: This happens when someone visits a very specific page, right? Before that DB performance is OK (i.e. at least not "dead")? Then it's most certainly some certain query that's giving problems. Use MongoDB profiling or Mongolab analytics or Kadira to find out which query it is and then narrow your question down to just this one query and give more details about the collection etc. Then it's much easier to help.

Comment: Hi Oskar. Thanks, I've been looking through Kadira without much luck, but going through the database logs I've found the problem query, and it is the one I was thinking it was...but I'm still not quite certain what's happening. I've edited my question to include the new information.

Comment: I don't have enough information to say why this is happening. The index `{"localID.space_id":1, startDateMs:1, endDateMs:-1}` should be better, but the index might not be the cause of this at all. [This article](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) will help you analyze your query. Also look at the articles in the **See also** section on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion with Mongolab support, I've got an answer (probably).

I'm on a shared cluster plan, so if a query hasn't been run for a few hours, it's flushed from memory to allow other users to access that block. The next time the query is run, it has to reload that data into memory, which in this case was taking a very long time. I've re-evaluated my indexing strategy, and I found that I'd missed the index I should have had -- I'd indexed `"localID.bldg_id"`, but forgotten to do a separate index that included `"localID.space_id"`, which was the important one for this issue.

I'll have to wait until the memory flushes before I can verify that this solution is working, but it seems likely.

If it doesn't, Mongolab's suggestion is to move to a dedicated cluster, rather than using shared.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the information, this is actually very useful. I'll keep this in mind when choosing a DB provider for my next project.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, thanks for helping me work through this.